# How to get access token from the Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring cloud gateway for create microservice gateway. The gateway is configured with `OAuth2` protocol. The application getting authenticated successfully. How to get access Token from gateway of the authenticated user?

I have implemented `GlobalFilter` to fetch the `Principal`. Following is the implementation:

```
return exchange.getPrincipal()
    .defaultIfEmpty(DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL).map(principal -> {
        // adds header to proxied request
        ServerHttpRequest.Builder b = exchange.getRequest().mutate();
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) principal;
            OAuth2User p = (OAuth2User) auth.getPrincipal();
            String userId = (String) p.getAttributes()
                    .getOrDefault("sub", new String());
            String firstName = (String) p.getAttributes()
                    .getOrDefault("given_name", new String());
            String lastName = (String) p.getAttributes()
                    .getOrDefault("family_name", new String());
            String name = (String) p.getAttributes()
                    .getOrDefault("preferred_username",
                            new String());
            String email = (String) p.getAttributes()
                    .getOrDefault("email",
                            new String());
        b.build();
        return exchange;
    }).flatMap(chain::filter);
    
private static Principal DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL = () -> "<EMPTY>";
```

And following is the SecurityConfig

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
  var authenticateExchangeOrUrl = http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(s.trim()).authenticated().and();
    securityFilterChain = authenticateExchangeOrUrl.oauth2Client().and().oauth2Login().and();

  return securityFilterChain
    .csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .build();
}
```

SecurityConfig is annotated with `@EnableWebFluxSecurity`. In application.yaml `spring.main.web-application-type: reactive` is added.

How to get access Token of the authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom configuration class and annotate it with @Configuration.

Step 1: Get the instance of ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository Interface

```
@Autowired
private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
```

Step 2: Apply Global filter and fetch the token from the OAuth2AuthorizedClient

```
    // For Getting token from request
    SecurityContextImpl context =
        exchange.getSession().toProcessor().block().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
        (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) context.getAuthentication();

    Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClient = clientRegistrationRepository
        .loadAuthorizedClient(oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            context.getAuthentication(), exchange);

    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClient.toProcessor().block();

    String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

    LOG.info("Access Token value: {}", accessToken);
```

Here is the complete configuration class which does the job perfectly.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayConfig.class);

  @Autowired
  private ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Bean
  public GlobalFilter customGlobalFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal().map(principal -> {
      if (principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        // For Getting token from request
        SecurityContextImpl context =
            exchange.getSession().toProcessor().block().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
            (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) context.getAuthentication();

        Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClient = clientRegistrationRepository
            .loadAuthorizedClient(oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                context.getAuthentication(), exchange);

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClient.toProcessor().block();

        String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

        LOG.info("Access Token value: {}", accessToken);
      }
      return exchange;
    }).flatMap(chain::filter).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
    }));
  }
}
```